# how can i use ionViewDidLoad() in a component?

Tags: angular, typescript, components, ionic3

Hello I'm working on `ionic 3` and I have data stored in local storage. I would like to use these data in a component , but `ionViewDidLoad` (which is work perfectly in a normal page) doesn't work on a component and I have got the below error:

[image: this error]

So please is there any other suggestions ?
component code (offre.ts):

```
    import { Component, Input , Output } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase, FirebaseListObservable } from "angularfire2/database"; 
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams} from 'ionic-angular';
import { NativeStorage } from '@ionic-native/native-storage';

@Component({
  selector: 'offre',
  templateUrl: 'offre.html',

})
export class OffreComponent {

    @Input('var') var;
    text: string;
    datas: FirebaseListObservable<any>;
    user : any ;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public db: AngularFireDatabase, public nativeStorage: NativeStorage) {
    this.datas=db.list('/posts');


  }

  ngAfterViewInit(){
    console.log(this.var);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code of your component?

Comment: @Sampath done ! Is ngOnInit  usefull ?

Comment: can you share the full stack trace of the error on console window?

Answer (score 1):

use ionViewCanEnter() which will be called before the ionViewDidLoad()

Answer (score 0):

I have tried it with my app and it doesn't give any run time error.But when you use the Angular components always try to use the Angular life cycle hooks.On your use case where you can use `ngAfterViewInit()`  hook.

[**Offical Doc**](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks)

> Respond after Angular initializes the component's views and child
>   views. Called once after the first ngAfterContentChecked(). A
>   component-only hook.